# 7-Zip for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 7-zip

7-Zip for Linux, does such a thing exist?

I mean actually 7-Zip or a port, not another compression tool or command.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219392/how-can-i-uncompress-a-7z-file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you use Debian or Ubuntu it is in the standard repositories (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/p7zip), so you can install it with as little as:

```
aptitude install p7zip
```

Or for the full version that includes archive creation and other format support (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/p7zip-full):

```
aptitude install p7zip-full
```

There are no doubt packages for it in the official repositories for most other distributions too, probably with the same package names.

Comment: its text mode only, but it runs under wine decently

Comment: @alpha1 You do not have it to run it under Wine if you do as this answers describes. With it you can use both the command line version and through File Roller.

Answer (score 2):

**[PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/)** - a Linux 7-Zip port; supports all file formats that 7-Zip supports. The GUI of PeaZip is also nicer than 7-Zip's.

Website: [Peazip.sourceforge.net](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/)
[Wikipedia article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/PeaZip)

Answer (score 1):

You can always run 7-Zip in [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29). It runs flawlessly.

Comment: You can also run Firefox, but why? The native port is perfect and ties into the file-roller interface.

Comment: cause fileroller and ark and them all suck something bad. PEazip is better and runs the same gui on all platorms

Comment: Hmm. Never heard of PeaZip before. Personally, I just use atool.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can download source code from [the download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and then compile it, or there are also some unofficial packages for Linux available on the very same page.

Answer (score 0):

[p7zip is a quick port of 7z.exe and 7za.exe (command line version of 7zip, see www.7-zip.org) for Unix.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall the Gnome Archive Manager has built-in support for 7-Zip.

Answer (score 0):

The default archive manager in GNOME and [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) supports read/writing 7-Zip files (I'm assuming it's builtin).