# Can I use 7Zip under Linux?

Tags: linux, 7-zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [7-zip for linux](https://superuser.com/questions/33133/7-zip-for-linux)

7Zip is a good compression-format. Can I produce such files or decompress them under Linux? I don't want to use emulation like Wine.

Comment: Did you read this; http://superuser.com/questions/33133/7-zip-for-linux?

Comment: No, I didn't saw that. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I would say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Use the command line port of 7zip:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/

> There is a port of the command line version to Linux/Unix.
>
> Download p7zip for Posix/Linux (x86 binaries and source code):
>
> Download p7zip

http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes... There are a bunch of unofficial Linux packages available as well as the source, which you can compile yourself all available on the [download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).