# Extract 7z files with standard linux tools?

Tags: linux, tar, 7-zip, extract

I know that you can extract `.7z` files with 7-zip.

Is there another standard linux program that can do this? Maybe one of these

```
tar
bzip2
xz
gzip
```

I will add that `bsdtar` can do this, but is not available on all systems.

Comment: similar question : [7zip for linux](http://superuser.com/q/33133/103134)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219392/how-can-i-uncompress-a-7z-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. 7-Zip archives use LZMA and LZMA2, which are not supported by standard tools (they also use bzip2, but you still need to decode the header).

Comment: Actually, `xz` uses LZMA as well. But yes, it still won't understand the rest of the 7z format.

Comment: It's funny how I was able to create a 7z archive via right-click compress, but was unable to decompress it afterwards xD classic linux.

Answer (score 60):

7-zip archives can be extracted with **p7zip** (http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) on Linux.  It is included in the repositories of: Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu and possibly other distributions too.

List contents with (lower case L, for list):

```
7za l myarchive.7z
```

Extract contents:

```
7za x myarchive.7z
```

Comment: **p7zip** is available in macports, as a binary. Just: `sudo port install p7zip`

Comment: on 64 bit RHEL 6, yum install p7zip.x86_64, and, if needed, yum install  p7zip-plugins.x86_64

Answer (score 3):

The "standard" way to work with 7-Zip archives on Unix is to use [P7ZIP](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/). But since the 7-Zip format was designed primarily for Windows, you shouldn't really expect `P7ZIP` to come installed on Linux distributions by default.

If you want the benefit of LZMA compression on Unix, prefer [XZ Utils](http://tukaani.org/xz/).

Answer (score 2):

I've could not find 7za in any yum repositories on RHEL/CentOS, so I've just downloaded the latest version of the source from sourceforge.net:

```sh
$ wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/16.02/p7zip_16.02_src_all.tar.bz2
```

(change "16.02" above to whatever latest version the time when you try to download, you can find out by going to https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/ ).

Being in the directory where you downloaded the p7zip archive, unpack it:

```sh
$ tar -xvjf p7zip_16.02_src_all.tar.bz2
```

Then run the make command as root user inside of extracted folder:

```sh
# make
# make install
```

It'll produce the `7za` binary in the `/usr/local/bin` directory (if you use RHEL7 at least):

```sh
$ whereis 7za
7za: /usr/local/bin/7za
```

Answer (score 2):

7za binary is part of p7zip package could be used for that. It could be installed from `epel` repository if you use RHEL/OL/CentOS (tested on RHEL6/RHEL7):

**RHEL6, 7:**

```
# rpm -Uvh http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
# yum install p7zip
```

This package have not been updated for a long time, but still could be used to extract files:

```
$ 7za x xyz_7zfile.7z
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried 7za on the first go but it did not work, so I tried using 7z with the same options and it works. Here is an example:

**To Extract:**

```sh
7z e xy213file.7z
```

Answer (score 0):

Package **p7zip** is available in macports, as a binary.

Just: `sudo port install p7zip`

And you're away! `7z x downloads/myfile.7z`

Same goes for CentOS but using yum:

`sudo yum install p7zip`